# Colorbox function is not working

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to create a HTML image gallery with colorbox jquery. But I can never get the images to open in a colorbox, instead they just open normally. Maybe I'm doing something terribly wrong. Here's the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Gallery </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
    });
    </script>

  <body>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>

    <div class="gallery">
    <a href="images/1.png"><img src="images/1.png"></a>
    <a href="images/2.png"><img src="images/2.png"></a>
    <a href="images/3.png"><img src="images/3.png"></a>    
    <a href="images/4.png"><img src="images/4.png"> </a>   
    <a href="images/5.png" ><img src="images/5"></a>   
    <a href="images/6.png" ><img src="images/6"></a>   
    <a href="images/7.png" ><img src="images/7"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you have both the minified and non-minified version of the colorbox scripts included, and I don't see the jQuery library being included. Also, the `a.gallery` selector isn't selecting anything, it's looking for an anchor element `<a>` with a class of `gallery`, a selector like `.gallery` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: After looking at the docs, the `<a>` elements should have the class of `gallery`, then your current selector will work. You'll still need to download and include jQuery (`<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`), and remove either the minified or non-minified script.

Comment: Agree w/ @mark.hch about needing to include jQuery's .js file, and being able to remove one of the colorbox .js files, but based on your above mark-up, I think you could change your selector from `a.gallery` to `.gallery a` (`a` elements that are descendants of an element w/ class `gallery`). Can't tell quickly from the docs and examples I've seen if you also need to incorporate the `rel` reference in your markup or not (though it'll certainly need some attention if you have multiple galleries of photos on the same page that you want to be distinctly grouped). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, try including jQuery, removing one of the colorbox scripts, and add the `gallery` class to the anchors. Like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Gallery </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css">
    <!-- include a compatible jquery version and remove one of the colorbox scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <div>
      <!-- Add the class of gallery to the anchors -->
      <a class="gallery" href="images/1.png"><img src="images/1.png"></a>
      <a class="gallery" href="images/2.png"><img src="images/2.png"></a>
      <a class="gallery" href="images/3.png"><img src="images/3.png"></a>    
      <a class="gallery" href="images/4.png"><img src="images/4.png"> </a>   
      <a class="gallery" href="images/5.png" ><img src="images/5"></a>   
      <a class="gallery" href="images/6.png" ><img src="images/6"></a>   
      <a class="gallery" href="images/7.png" ><img src="images/7"></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```